# Validating binding, depending on which button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I searched a lot, but I didn't find the right solution.

I have a `TextBox`, `DataGridView`, 3 `Button`s and a `BindingSource`.

When I click my `Button` 'Change' I set the binding and data are loaded from `DataGridView` to `TextBox`, which works:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("text", bindingSource, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

When I click now `Button` 'Cancel' the binding will be cleared:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Clear();
```

but the data is still transferred to the `DataGridView`. I think it's because of `OnPropertyChanged`. When I change it to `OnValidation`, I know it will only be saved, when it's validated.

But how can I validate it or refuse validation? I have 2 `Button`s, and depending on whether the 'Save' button or the 'Cancel' button is clicked, it should be transferred to `DataGridView` or not.

And also with the event

```
textBox.Validating += textBox_Validating;
```

I didn't get it running, because this function is called before I can click a button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create binding with `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never` and store it in a form level variable (field). Then you can use [`WriteValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Binding.WriteValue);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method to apply the changes (respectively [`ReadValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.readvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to revert the changes).

Something like this:

*form:*

```
Binding nameBinding;
```

*Change button click:*

```
nameBinding = textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
```

*Cancel button click:*

```
nameBinding.ReadValue();
textBox.DataBindings.Clear();
nameBinding = null;
```

*Save button click:*

```
nameBinding.WriteValue();
textBox.DataBindings.Clear();
nameBinding = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great :) I use now an List<Binding>, because I have more controls and with foreach I read or write all values.

Comment: Hi Ivan: Now I found the Interface `IEditableObject` with `BeginEdit`, `CancelEdit` and `EndEdit`. Is this something similar like `ReadValue` and `WriteValue`?

Comment: Hi @Beetee, Not exactly. First, it requires your objects to implement that interface. And the implementation of the `BeginEdit` should somehow store all the property values somewhere in order to be able to restore them if `CancelEdit` is called. While the above technique has no such requirements because it keeps the new values inside the controls, and updates the data source only when specifically requested.

Comment: OK, so the above solution does nearly the same, but with less configuration effort?!

Comment: Well, while both approaches do nearly the same, they do it quite differently. (1) BeginEdit: IEditableObject should create and store snapshot of the property values; the above solution does not require any action (2) CancelEdit: IEditableObject should restore the property values and free the snapshot, bound controls are updated automatically; the above solution needs to manually force controls to re read the values (3) EndEdit: IEditableObject has to free the snapshot. No control action is needed (since the controls contain the most recent data); the above solution need to manually ..

Comment: ... force the controls to push their current values to data source. IEditableObject solution is preferable, but requires more coding in the data source objects. From the other side the data binding is simpler.